# How to get last element in the .find() object by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have DOM like this:

```
<div class="parent">
   <button class="add-tr">Add</button>
   <table class="child">
   <tr data="0"></tr>
   <tr data="1"></tr>
   ...
   </table>
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <button class="add-tr">Add</button>
   <table class="child">
   <tr data="0"></tr>
   <tr data="1"></tr>
   ...
   </table>
</div>
...
```

When I click on the Add button, I would like to get the value of the data attribute from the last  of it own parent class.

I am using this method to get the last element,but it doesn't work.

```
$('.add-tr').click( function() {
   var last = $(this).parent().find('.child:last').attr('data');
   alert(last);
})
```

Any idea why? Or any other suggestion to get the last element in the table?

**UPDATE**
Yes, I found the problem, turn out is I forgot the 'tr'. Thanks for your guys answer. All your guys giving the correct answer, I wish I can accept all your answers. Thanks

Comment: `$(this).parent().children().last()`

Comment: yet another variant: `var last = $(this).parent().find('.child :last').attr('data');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'.child:last'` selector will select the last element having `child` class. As `child` class is applied to `<table>`, this selector will select table element, while you want to select last `<tr>`.

As there is no `data` attribute on `<table>`, `.attr('data')` on it will return `undefined`.

To get the value of `data` attribute on last `<tr>` use the selector `tr:last`.

```
var value = $(this)           // Button that is clicked
    .parent()                 // Direct parent element i.e. div.parent
    .find('.child tr:last')   // Get the last <tr> inside .child
    .attr('data');            // Get value of data attribute
```

As the `.child` element is next to the button, `next()` can be used to get the `table.child` element.

```
var value = $(this)           // Button that is clicked
    .next('.child')           // Next element i.e. table
    .find('tr:last')          // Get last <tr>
    .attr('data');            // Get value of "data" attribute
```

---

I'll recommend to use `data-*` attribute to store data in custom attribute.

```
<tr data-num="0">Foo</tr>
<tr data-num="1">Bar</tr>
```

And to get the value of custom data attribute use `data()`

```
.data('num')
```

---

If you just want to get the index of the last `tr`, there is no need to store that on element. You can get the index by using the `index()`.

```
.index()
```

This will return index of an element. Note that this is zero-based index which is exactly how you want.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
   var last = $(this).parent().find('.child').find('tr').last().attr('data');
```

In your example you get last `table`, but you need get last `tr`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vr1knxqq/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".parent").click(function(){

$(this + " tr:last-child").attr("data");

});
```

should do.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost correct, you missed `tr:last` , i.e.:

```
var last = $(this).parent().find('.child tr:last').attr('data');
```

---

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/vr1knxqq/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-tr').click( function(event) {
   var last = $(event.target).next().find("tr").last().attr("data");
   alert(last);
})
```

[fiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/3wusd5gp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of the `tr` elements by using `find('.child tr')`
and to get the last element in that array you can use `last()`.
Putting it all together you have this:

```
$('.add-tr').click( function() {
   var lastTr = $(this).parent().find('.child tr').last(),
       lastData = $(lastTr).attr('data');

   alert(lastData);
});
```

I have setup a codepen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzmKg to show this working.